# TypeScript can't find imports inside Vue class component when trying to reify $refs even though they can be accessed when adding them as components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making a [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) 2.0 Progressive Web App with the [Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/), and I'm trying to make the drawer in the left slot of the layout close when a menu item is clicked.

This is the component script `Home.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

import {
  QIcon,
  QLayout,
  QList,
  QListHeader,
  QItem,
  QItemMain,
  QItemSide,
  QToolbar,
  QToolbarTitle,
} from 'quasar';

@Component({
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    QIcon,
    QLayout,
    QList,
    QListHeader,
    QItem,
    QItemMain,
    QItemSide,
    QToolbar,
    QToolbarTitle,
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {

  $refs: {
    layout: QLayout // Cannot find name 'QLayout'
  };

  public newPainting() {
    this.$refs.layout.toggleLeft();
    this.$router.push(`painting/new`);
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile because of the `Cannot find name 'QLayout'` error, but it works when I change the type of `$refs.layout` to `any`, like this:

```
$refs: {
    layout: any
};
```

I'm confused as to why it can't find `QLayout`, since it's being used in the `@Component()` decorator.

This is the `Home.vue` file for the component (mostly taken from the default one you get when you use quasar-cli to scaffold a layout):

```
<template>
  <q-layout ref="layout">
    <q-toolbar slot="header">
      <!-- opens drawer below-->
      <button class="hide-on-drawer-visible" @click="$refs.layout.toggleLeft()">
        <q-icon name="menu"></q-icon>
      </button>

      <q-toolbar-title>
        echroma
      </q-toolbar-title>
    </q-toolbar>

    <!-- Left Side Panel -->
    <div slot="left">
      <q-list no-border link inset-delimiter>
        <q-list-header>Menu</q-list-header>

        <q-item @click="newPainting()">
          <q-item-side icon="add_to_photos" />
          <q-item-main label="New Painting" sublabel="Start evolving a new painting!" />
        </q-item>

      </q-list>
    </div>

    <router-view />
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import Home from './Home'
    export default Home
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Is there any reason why `QLayout` wouldn't be accessible from inside the class declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because `QLayout` is an object and not a type.

In your code, the instance variable `$refs` is declared but not initialized. The syntax with `:` is for declaring a type.

```
export default class Home extends Vue {
  $refs: {
    layout: QLayout // Cannot find name 'QLayout'
  };
  // ...
}
```

Maybe you would like to initialize it?

```
export default class Home extends Vue {
  $refs = {
    layout: QLayout // Affect the variable 'QLayout' to the key 'layout'
  };
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The reason I had it using a `:` is because of [this link](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/av-ts/wiki/FAQ#2-property-reification) I found when googling for a solution. I don't have enough rep to mark your answer correct though :|